# How to hide links, present in the attribution for decorative images, from the screen reader?

Tags: html, accessibility

I have used background images and other decorative images on my website with attribution. I want to set aria-hidden to "true" for these images. However the attributions have links, since links are interactive elements, these cannot be removed from the accessibility tree. How do I handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `tabindex="-1"` on the links they will no longer be within the focus order on the page, that will reduce how often they get read out.

There is still a chance with normal reading that these links get found (and when listing all links on the page) so your best bet would be to set an `aria-label` on the links that says "attribution link for decorative image").

Yes this would be annoying but it is better than a non descriptive link text as then screen reader users may follow the link just to see what it is (as they will assume you forget to include link text as it happens so often!)

### Check the license

You will find that in a few attribution style licenses you can actually place the attribution message elsewhere and in others that it does not **have** to be a link.

In that case either have a page on your site called "attribution" and list all image attribution there or don't have it as a link, at which point it becomes easy to hide with `aria-hidden="true"`.